# Error: K-Mean Clustering Algorithm data plots is not visible in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, k-means

Hi I want to implement the K-Means Clustering Algorithm.

For this I am getting data from sample.csv file and apply K-Means clustering on it. Here is my source code

**## K-Means.py**

```
# clustering dataset
import pandas

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

variables = pandas.read_csv("/Users/srikanth/Desktop/sample1.csv")
print(variables)
x1 = variables[['X']]
x2 = variables[['Y']]
print(x1)
print(x2)

plt.plot()
plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 10])
plt.title('Dataset')
plt.xlabel('X - Values')
plt.ylabel('Y - Values')
plt.scatter(x1, x2)
plt.show()

# create new plot and data
plt.plot()
X = np.array(list(zip(x1, x2))).reshape(len(x1), 2)
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r']
markers = ['o', 'v', 's']

# KMeans algorithm
K = 3
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=K).fit(X)

plt.plot()
for i, l in enumerate(kmeans_model.labels_):
    plt.plot(x1[i], x2[i], color=colors[l], marker=markers[l],ls='None')
    plt.xlim([0, 10])
    plt.ylim([0, 10])
    plt.show()
```

After I run the above code in terminal, the output like:

[image: Console Output]

[image: plots visualization]

The above image don't show any clustered data plots, So I want to see my clustered data plots visually. How can I fix this.
I am new to this area.
Thank you

Comment: If you are talking about first scatter, I think you have to change the limits. Because of having only upto 10 where as the data lies around ([150, 190]) and ([40, 90]). Btw you have a plot in the loop and you are plot.show for every point??.

Comment: BTW, you are not *implementing* K-means, you just want to use an existing implementation (scikit-learn's here)...

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry and Thank you for pointing this. I am new to this area.

Comment: You are very welcome - no worries & keep on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

variables = pandas.read_csv("/Users/srikanth/Desktop/sample1.csv")
print(variables)
x1 = variables[['X']]
x2 = variables[['Y']]
plt.plot()
plt.xlim([150, 190])
plt.ylim([40, 90])
plt.title('Dataset')
plt.xlabel('X - Values')
plt.ylabel('Y - Values')
plt.scatter(x1, x2)
plt.show()
```

The scatter that it produces for the 10 points is :

[image]

For the code using the kmeans-clustering model, you are plotting for every label in the the model which will produce 10 plots. Just changing the limits should do the magic.

Comment: thank you so much its worked. But I changed the limit values like plt.xlim([100, 150])
plt.ylim([40, 60]) after run these values again it is not showing the any plots even values 46, 52, 55, 59, 60 are available in the Y. whats the mistake I did??

Comment: @WeCan nothing should be shown for the plot because no value comes on the x_axis(for the chosen limits) and therefore it cannot plot any points on the graph.

Comment: thank you , also please suggest me any ref links for learning machine learning I am completely new bee to this area. Thank you